# Extending from Laravel 5 core - SqlServerConnection

Tags: laravel

i need extends the `Illuminate\Database\SqlServerConnection` to overwrite one function. I've tried create my own DatabaseServiceProvider and put an use `App\Libraries\Extensions\Connectors\ConnectionFactory` but the ConnectionFactory is not overloading, only DatabaseServiceProvider

Answer (score 0):

The first thing the `ConnectionFactory::createConnection()` method does is to check if the `db.connection.{$driver}` alias is bound, and if so, it returns that connection object. If it is not bound, it returns the base connection object (`Illuminate\Database\SqlServerConnection` for the `sqlsrv` driver).

Therefore, all you need to do to use your own custom connection is to bind the `db.connection.sqlsrv` alias to your custom `SqlServerConnection` class. You can see an example of this in the [`shiftonelabs/laravel-nomad`](https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-nomad/blob/1.0.0/src/LaravelNomadServiceProvider.php#L29) package (full disclosure: written by me).

You can create a new service provider in which to do this, or you can just add the line to your existing `AppServiceProvider`.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('db.connection.sqlsrv', 'Your\Custom\SqlServerConnection');
    }
}
```